# Finding the feasible region of a system of convex / monotone inequalities?

Tags: inequality, convex-optimization, discrete-optimization, polytopes, discrete-geometry

Let $x$ and $y$ be variables in $\mathbb{R}^{+}$, and assume I have a system of inequalities, e.g.:

$$
\begin{align}
x \geq 1 \tag{1}\\
x \leq 5 \tag{2}\\
y \geq 1 \tag{3}\\
\log x + \log y \leq \log 6 \tag{4}\\
\end{align}
$$

where some of the inequalities (here: 4) are nonlinear but convex and monotone, such as the sum of log variables above. I have plotted this example below. This would be a pretty straightforward problem if I only had the linear inequalities (1) to (3). In this instance, I could for example use the [simplex algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_algorithm). However, the presence of the nonlinear inequality (4) complicates matters.

**My question**: I am interested in a method or an algorithm that finds the vertices of the feasible region. Is this possible? If it is possible, can you recommend a method or some keywords for further study? If it is not possible, why?

(Mind that I am not interested in solving an optimization problem on the polytope - I only want the vertices of the feasible region.)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have two vertices: (1,1) and (5,1).  You can find the other two by plugging in x=1 and x=5 into (4).

Let’s try x=1.  $\log(1)=0$ so (4) becomes $\log(y) \leq \log(6)$, which is true iff $y\leq 6$.  So the vertex is (1,6).  Do the same with x=5 and you’ve found the four vertices.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I appreciate it! In this example, I suppose this approach would work. There might be some degenerate cases in which this might not work, though: for instance, if we had another nonlinear inequality instead of $y \geq 1$ (or two other arbitrarily rotated parallel boundaries), then we would have no vertices to start from. Do you have a suggestion how to deal with these cases?

Comment: @J.Galt It depends on a whole lot of things: how complicated can the functions be, how precise must the locations be, how many constraints are there?

Comment: Phew, in the case I have in mind, the setting would be a nightmare: there would be a lot of variables and a lot of inequalities, so I definitely need a strategy that works in higher dimensions (I just used two above for illustration purposes). The good news is that the functions would be simple: either conventional linear inequalities, or sums of logarithms, as above.